# find exact object in image - template matching?

Tags: android, ios, opencv

What technique has to be used to find exact (!) objects inside an image? So not the machine learning default tutorial case of cats vs. dogs or categorizing a flower, not even find a rose inside an image (as roses can look different) but the exactly find e.g. a book/cd/.../cover.

So pretty much what Apple does with its latest iOS 11.3beta1 (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/recognizing_images_in_an_ar_experience) but more general. I'm really impressed by the performance, you only have to input one image of a book cover and it finds it immediately in the camera live view - without long training in neural networks with big GPUs etc.

Eg. OpenCV Template Matching sounds promising although it's not two images that are compared but an image and a camera live feed.

Comment: "You only have to input one image of a book cover and it finds it immediately in the camera live view - without long training in neural networks with big GPUs etc." this isn't surprising at all---the network has already been trained. You're not feeding it new training examples, and it's not learning as you use it. It just performs a few matrix multiplications to get you the output you want. This is the whole point of neural nets---some big company with a lot of power can train them, and then just ship the trained models.

Comment: "What technique has to be used to find exact (!) objects inside an image?" Template matching indeed does this but note that exact means exact. If the image you're looking for is rotated, skewed, upside-down, scaled, stretched, etc, template matching will not work. "it's not two images that are compared but an image and a camera live feed." A live camera feed is nothing more than a sequence of images (frames). You just perform template matching on each frame of the video with the chosen template.